# How to run term statistics efficiently in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use the following code to find term frequency for a document.

```
POST myindex/mydoc/1/_termvectors?fields=fields.bodyText&pretty=true
{
    "term_statistics":true,
    "filter":{

        "max_doc_freq":300,
        "min_doc_freq":50
    }
}
```

In my index there are 1 million documents. How to run this statistics more efficiently for each document?
By efficiently I mean for example: The word `the` in doc 1 can also appear in doc 2, so when I run the statistics for doc 2 there is no need to calculate `the` again(assuming that my index has not been updated for each document).